# Excluding background image from saving/printing with fabricjs (1.7.20)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

How can I exclude my canvas background image from the final result when I save or print using the following code? Sidenote: The save/print doesn't seem to work in fiddles but does on my machine/server. Hopefully, the code is enough for you to point me in the right direction!

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);
canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/4yOoOzl.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {});

// Save
function download(url, name) {
  // make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
  $('<a>').attr({
    href: url,
    download: name
  })[0].click();
}

function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  //  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  download(canvas.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  }), name + '.png');
}

// Print
function printCanvas() {
  var dataUrl = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL( /* data multiplier?*/ ); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
  var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  windowContent += '<html>'
  windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
  windowContent += '<body>'
  windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
  windowContent += '</body>';
  windowContent += '</html>';
  var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(windowContent);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas><br>
<button onclick="downloadFabric(canvas,'canvasname');">Download</button>
<button onclick="printCanvas()">Print</button>
```

Comment: Draw on a transparent canvas and have the background image on an element beneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  //  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  var bgImage = canvas.backgroundImage;
  canvas.backgroundImage = null;
  canvas.renderAll();
  download(canvas.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  }), name + '.png');
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(bgImage, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
}
```

Or before downloading you can make `canvas.backgroundImage = null` and after download insert that image again.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);
canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.imgur.com/4yOoOzl.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {crossOrigin:"anonymous"});
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({radius:50}))
// Save
function download(url, name) {
  // make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
  $('<a>').attr({
    href: url,
    download: name
  })[0].click();
}

function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  //  convert the canvas to a data url and download it.
  var bgImage = canvas.backgroundImage;
  canvas.backgroundImage = null;
  canvas.renderAll();
  download(canvas.toDataURL({
    multiplier: 2
  }), name + '.png');
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(bgImage, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
}

// Print
function printCanvas() {
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL( /* data multiplier?*/ ); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
  var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  windowContent += '<html>'
  windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
  windowContent += '<body>'
  windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
  windowContent += '</body>';
  windowContent += '</html>';
  var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(windowContent);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas><br>
<button onclick="downloadFabric(canvas,'canvasname');">Download</button>
<button onclick="printCanvas()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was using CSS to set my background image:

```
canvas { background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/4yOoOzl.jpg"); }
```